# How to set up a PhoneGap project in WebStorm

Tags: ios, cordova, requirejs, webstorm

I am trying to make a phone gap app, specifically for the iOS platform.  However I want to develop in the WebStorm IDE, push my project to a repository, and then use PhoneGap Build.

I've downloaded PhoneGap version 3.1.0-0.15.0, created a project for the iOS platform, and added all of the plugins I think I will need to the project.  That all seems to be ok, I can run the Xcode project and get the little onDeviceReady hello world program.

Now where things get a bit more confusing for me is:

1. If I wanted to start building a web app in WebStorm using PhoneGap what would I move into my WebStorm project?  Do I need to take something from my PhoneGap project directory?  And if so what pieces do I take?  Do I need to put it in as an external library, or can I just plop it into my root directory?
2. If I wanted to use a module loader like requirejs as well, are there any additional hoops I would have to jump through or issues I'd have if I tried to make phone gap a module?  Or is it a better idea to just load my cordova.js file before I load requires?

I've seen a lot of posts that have bits and pieces, or some that tell you how to set things up specifically for Android, or using an earlier version of PhoneGap with a different file structure.  But have been unable to find anything that really explains the whole picture to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can work with your favorite IDE, no problem at all. Developing with Phonegap is more or less the same as developing a web page, with Phonegap being only the connection between webview and actual device. Therefore almost any approach that works for web will do with Phonegap, just keep in mind that mobile devices have limited resources, so be careful not to bloat your app with frameworks, plugins
and images...

The code resides in the **www folder** of your app, so you can either work there or choose another workspace and copy/paste (or build) your code for testing.

Besides testing in a simulator, an actual device or in the browser (I tend to do that when I don't use much of Phonegaps functionality), [Ripple emulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com) comes in handy. You will need chrome browser to use it.

I personally use a combination of phonegap, jquery mobile, require.js and backbone.js.

You might also have a look at [Grunt phonegap build](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-phonegap-build) to automate the process of sending your data to Phonegap build.

Please take this as a consideration rather than an answer, there are many different approaches and I am just trying to narrow it down. I would recommend to have a look at the many useful boilerplates out there and choose the one that fits your style of coding best...

Answer (score 0):

Well as you likely know from...

```
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html
```

[after setup] you only need to put...

```
cordova run
```

on the command line.
I tried putting via Run>Edit Configurations... 
a new conf with a Before Launch external tool with the program as "cordova" and paramaters as "run" with the correct working directory but alas...

```
Error running cordova: Cannot run program "cordova"
```

it seems to not be run in a proper command prompt. so just do it manually.
unless someone else knows how to rig it to work, it's all new to me at this point.

Maybe I'll figure something out and amend this later.
oh and use weinre to debug the more complicated remote stuff.
It's a NodeJS package too.

I also had to put null.html as the URL to open... so anyway that whole route you asking about is really not the right tool for the job. Just stick to running the cordova command line yourself.